# Django Session Variables Overwritten with Concurrent Requests

Tags: python, ajax, django, session, asynchronous

I am using an architecture that sends AJAX requests to a Django view to update session variables. These requests can sometimes overlap. I've been noticing session variables being cleared.

What appears to be happening is that the session is retrieved from the database at the start of the request and then saved at the end. If another requests updates the session, the previous one has stale data that it ends up rewriting to the database.

Is there a way to force Django to only save session fields that it has changed?

Comment: No, because the session is saved as a single pickled value. Could you use a specific model with individual fields?

Comment: Do you mean make my own session model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, @kyle-piefer: I have the same problem. I get the session through `request.session`. Do you know if it's possible to combine this with `select_for_update`, so no parallel requests can update the session data?